# Double Click/Snigle click hold and drag behaviour is weird in pycharm

Tags: pycharm, ubuntu-18.04

When I double click / single click hold and drag across text the cursor behaves as if I have pressed "insert" key. I am not able to select the text and say copy/paste or cut it using shortcuts or even delete it using backsapace or delete key.
Another thing that happens after I double click is if I press "X" ubuntu makes that sound that it makes when the terminal line is empty and one presses backspace (empty line sound in terminal)
OS - Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
PyCharm - Community
Screen Recording - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RElBhi--f-qT7evZfpHTkBUl0kd0Nrv7/view?usp=sharing
In the beginning of the video I click and hold to select text then I press space and instead of replacing the text it selects even more text.
Please ask for additional details if needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for changed caret behaviour:

**1. Disable 'block caret'**

[image: disable block caret]
[Jet Brains Community](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206159619-How-do-I-change-cursor-from-a-block-back-to-)

**2. VIM editor enabled**

Preferences > Plugins > IdeaVim then restarting

**3. Column Selection Mode enabled**

> You can make a multiple selection of code in columns. To enable or disable the column selection mode, press Alt+Shift+Insert or use the context menu of the editor...

[Jet Brains Doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/working-with-source-code.html#multiple_cursor)